# How to set initial values for decision variables in Pyomo model

Tags: variables, initialization, pyomo

I am working on a Mixed Integer Programming Model in Pyomo and hope to set initial values for my decision variables (which is a matrix in my case). How can I do that?

To be more specific, the  following can succeed in setting a initial guess of 2 on the (scalar) decision variable y.

```
model.y = Var(initialize=2)
```

However, what if model.x is a 3-by-2 matrix and I want to make an initial guess for each of its elements? For instance, I tried something like the following without success:

```
model.I = RangeSet(3)
model.J = RangeSet(2)
model.K = Set(within=model.I *model.J)
model.x = Var(model.K, initialize=np.randomize(3,2))
```

Could someone help with this? Thanks much.

Comment: I think you get this error "module 'numpy' has no attribute 'randomize'". Numpy has random module.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you would like to initialize the values of each element to. For example, if you want every element in `model.x` to be initialized to the same value, such as 1, you can do the following:

```
from pyomo.environ import Var, RangeSet, ConcreteModel

model = ConcreteModel()

model.I = RangeSet(3)
model.J = RangeSet(2)
model.x = Var(model.I, model.J, initialize=1)
```

Alternatively, if you have specific values in mind for each element, you can construct a dictionary of indexed keys to values:

```
model = ConcreteModel()

model.I = RangeSet(1)
model.J = RangeSet(2)
init_dict = {(1,1):2,
             (1,2):4}
model.x = Var(model.I, model.J, initialize=init_dict)
```

For larger sets, you can use something like `itertools.product` to generate all of the keys and `np.random.randomint` to generate a random value with list comprehension. This would let you add optional arguments like upper/lower random value bounds. Use `model.x.pprint()` to see the initialized values.